# How to save user's input (mage file) in KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I made a simple app that accepts users' input (Image file). But whenever it is closes the inputed file is losted, (of course, I did not make a way for it to be saved).
Please, I'd like the inputed image file to be available, when next the app is opened, so please how do I save the inputed image file (Perharbs you could show me a sample code, direct me somewhere or anything, I'd really appreciate). Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Here's my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from plyer import filechooser

Window.size = (300, 530)

KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        id: progress_toolbar
        title: 'Progress'

    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 2
            adaptive_height: True
            spacing: (10, 15)
            padding: [25, 25]

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'center'
                text: 'Before'

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'center'
                text: 'Now'

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 120, 220
                elevation: 15
                radius: 8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "camera-outline"
                    user_font_size: "24sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: app.file_chooser1()
                Image:
                    id: img1
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    # size_hint_y: .5

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 120, 220
                elevation: 15
                radius: 8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "camera-outline"
                    user_font_size: "24sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: app.file_chooser2()
                Image:
                    id: img2
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    # size_hint_y: .5


            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Date'
                width: 100

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Date'
                width: 100

"""


class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def file_chooser1(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected1)

    def file_chooser2(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected2)

    def selected1(self, selection1):
        self.root.ids.img1.source = selection1[0]

    def selected2(self, selection2):
        self.root.ids.img2.source = selection2[0]


Example().run()
```

Again, Thanks a lot for your help, I'll appreciate any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should **log** the image files.

**How ?**

You can use the `kivy.storage.jsonstore.JsonStore` class for **logging** like a **database**.

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore('database.json')

...

def selected1(self, selection1):
    self.root.ids.img1.source = selection1[0]
    files_list = store['database']['files']
    files_list.append(selection1[0])
    store.put('database', files=files_list)
```

like this. I hope i could help you. You can search the **How to use JsonStore Kivy ?**

Comment: Thanks a lot @efpyc for for help, I implemented your code, but am getting a `KeyError: 'database'`.

Comment: Your `database.json` file should looks like that:

`{"database": {"files": []}}`

Comment: I don't really understand, where should I add this `{"database": {"files": []}}`

Comment: Create a new  file named `database.json` and write `{"database": {"files": []}}` to file

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It does actually save but it doesn't load the image.. To be available when the app is reopen.